# keep margin between text and image

Tags: html, css, angular, service

In my code I use the service and retrieve data from the backend. I have code like this to retrieve the content.

```
<div class="body" *ngFor='let topic of topics | async'>
   <div [innerHTML]="topic.content"></div>
</div>
```

This topic.content have some text and image. What I want is keep margin between this text and image. But I have no idea to do that. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Can you include the text and image code that is placed in the `innerHTML`, and also your CSS? Otherwise it'll be hard to figure out what your project looks like.

Comment: You will have to either 1) change data structure on backend to include a desired css formatting inside the .content field, then have that css class(es) defined in the app itself (or if it's just style, not a class, you don't need app css), or 2) split the .content in ts method into text/img parts and add formatting.

Comment: @MishaMashina can you tell me how can I split the .contetnt in ts method

Comment: just use .css in your **styles.css** (the common styles you shared in all the application)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the .content value?

Comment: @MishaMashina it is something like below
(this is some text
this is image)

Comment: Does the .content have image inside the tag <img>? Or is it just a link for image? How is the text divided from image? It would really help just to see the example.

Comment: @MishaMashina yes it is inside the <img>. text is inside the <p>.  when I inspect I can see those tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, if you change that inner div to:

```
<div class="splitter" [innerHTML]="topic.content"></div>
```

then you can put in styles.css (global styles, not component's css file) something like:

```
.splitter > img { 
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

But I don't know how you styled the 'body' class of the parent div and if there's styling in the .content value itself, so you will need to play a bit with that .splitter class.